Why does GCP L7 application load balancer gRPC health check not support TLS?
I’m trying to set up a GCP L7 application load balancer with gke/k8s grpc services as backend (using gke ingress). I’ve noticed that the built-in gRPC health check is not supported over TLS.
Why is this a limitation? What technical challenges prevent the health check from supporting TLS? If LoadBalancer gRPC over TLS is already supported for regular traffic, and a health check is essentially just a gRPC call, why isn't TLS health check supported?
I am curious to understand the underlying issues or considerations that might make implementing this feature difficult.

APMK TLS handshakes may result in latency. Using TLS for health checks could put more load on the load balancer and backend services, which might impact the performance and scalability and also as health checks need to execute at a higher frequency ensuring the certificate checks like certificate validations, updates and configuration will add more complexity to the deployment process.
